# NoSuchMethodError When Adding Third @Field in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, django-rest-framework, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Retrofit 2.0 to make requests to my REST API. I have the following method that works fine:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/mobile_register/")
Call<MobileAuthUserJSON> createUser(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

However, when I add a third field like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/mobile_register/")
Call<MobileAuthUserJSON> createUser(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password,
                                    @Field("phone_number") String phone_num);
```

I am greeted with a:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method createUser(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lretrofit2/Call; in
>   class Lcom/jiaohuan/jiaohuan/jsonData/UserAPI; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.jiaohuan.jiaohuan.jsonData.UserAPI' appears in
>   /data/data/com.jiaohuan.jiaohuan/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex)

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening, it can't be an error with the server because:

1) The app crashes before it even makes the request

2) I have already set up the server to handle receiving the "phone_number" field.

Comment: I don't know this framework but it seems you are (implicitly or explicitly) calling `createUser` by passing two string parameters somewhere in your project : `/data/data/com.jiaohuan.jiaohuan/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex`

Comment: I'll look into that. That .dex file wasn't created by me, that's part of the IDE generated files I believe

Comment: What does it look like ?

Comment: I cannot seem to find it on my local machine.

Comment: @ethanzh , i am faceing the problem.do have any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When I experienced this error the solution was to do a clean rebuild of the project.